# Speeding up the viewport

Tags: interface, performance

I just had a shock when I opened 2.28c (it's been far too long)

The drawing was super fast on my EEEPC. All the time I thought my graphics card was slow (and it is by comparison) when actually Blender 2.7x just draws all kinds of fancy stuff in fancy ways which eat processing time ( I know it's not true but just out of spite I blame all the little numbutton arrows).

Are there any impactful settings that would make it easier on the graphics card? It's not hardware specific.

Also interesting: why exactly is it so much slower? One example: mapped planes are much faster than image empties or background images. Assume no knowledge of OpenGL except the spelling.